# How to extract the text of a PDF document with Automator, and save it in a directory

Tags: macos, automator, pdf

How can you modify the output folder of the Extract PDF text action ? I made a basic workflow to extract the text of PDF files, but the output folder is stuck to `Desktop`. I can change it in Automator, but the changes are not saved. It reverts to Desktop when I reopen the workflow.

[image: Automator]
Bureau means Desktop. This is the one that refuses to be set.

Comment: I may have a solution, but can you show the workflow first so I can get a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: The whole workflow consists in one action:extract PDF text. It just refuses to accept another output directory

Comment: Do you have the 'show this action.." ticked in the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly choosing a directory in the drop-down menu, which for some reason, doesn't work, choose: New variable.

Then choose a name, and a directory where you want the files to be saved.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug with Automator, as I can reproduce the same problem.

The workaround is to have Automator move the file to your desired destination after the text is extracted. Just add the **Move Finder Items** action (sorry, I'm not sure of the exact french translation) after the Extract action, and set it to your desired directory.

[image: Move Finder Items action]