# Automator's "Extract to PDF" does not remember output folder

Tags: automator

I'm trying to create a simple `Folder Action` with `Automator` (on macOS Sierra 10.12.2) that watches a folder for `PDF` files and convert these to `TXT` files and save it to a subfolder. The problem is that the selected subfolder is not being stored. When I hit save and open the action again, the subfolder is set to its default `Desktop`.

This is how it looks like when I hit `save`. When I close Automator, open it again and select this recent action, `Save Output to` is set to `Desktop`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known bug that hasn't been resolved since 2012:

[How to extract the text of a PDF document with Automator, and save it in a directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69001/how-to-extract-the-text-of-a-pdf-document-with-automator-and-save-it-in-a-direc)